# Why does 1st degree independent variable in poly(x,2) does not generate its estimate in the multiple regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression

My regression model has two kinds of polynomial terms, but one of its first degree variable (here `age`) fails to generate its estimate while `exper` and `exper^2` terms do not fail. I want to understand why.

My code is:

```
library(wooldridge)
data('card')

fit1_ols <- lm(lwage~educ + poly(exper, 2) + black + smsa + south + poly(age, 2),  data = card)
fit2_ols <- lm(lwage~educ + poly(exper, 2) + black + smsa + south + poly(age, 2) + motheduc + fatheduc, data = card)

summ(fit1_ols)
summ(fit2_ols)
```

The outcomes are respectively:

```
----------------------------------------------------
                         Est.   S.E.   t val.      p
--------------------- ------- ------ -------- ------
(Intercept)              5.26   0.05   107.40   0.00
educ                     0.07   0.00    21.10   0.00
poly(exper, 2)1          8.93   0.49    18.05   0.00
poly(exper, 2)2         -2.71   0.41    -6.66   0.00
black                   -0.19   0.02   -10.75   0.00
smsa                     0.16   0.02    10.36   0.00
south                   -0.12   0.02    -8.23   0.00
poly(age, 2)1            ???                           
poly(age, 2)2            0.17   0.41     0.41   0.68
----------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------
                         Est.   S.E.   t val.      p
--------------------- ------- ------ -------- ------
(Intercept)              5.18   0.06    87.10   0.00
educ                     0.07   0.00    16.99   0.00
poly(exper, 2)1          9.45   0.60    15.65   0.00
poly(exper, 2)2         -2.89   0.51    -5.67   0.00
black                   -0.16   0.02    -6.69   0.00
smsa                     0.16   0.02     8.74   0.00
south                   -0.11   0.02    -6.22   0.00
poly(age, 2)1            ???                           
poly(age, 2)2            0.20   0.49     0.41   0.69
motheduc                 0.01   0.00     2.24   0.03
fatheduc                -0.00   0.00    -0.25   0.80
----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the normal `summary` instead of `summ` (for which you did load the respective library), R tells you the problem:

```
library(wooldridge)
data('card')

fit1_ols <- lm(lwage~educ + poly(exper, 2) + black + smsa + south + poly(age, 2),  data = card)
fit2_ols <- lm(lwage~educ + poly(exper, 2) + black + smsa + south + poly(age, 2) + motheduc + fatheduc, data = card)

summary(fit1_ols)
summary(fit2_ols)
```

[image: fit1_ols]
[image: fit2_ols]

As you can see, the error message indicates "not defined because of singularities." Here is a [helpful post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13465/how-to-deal-with-an-error-such-as-coefficients-14-not-defined-because-of-singu) on how to deal with this issue. Basically, the missing variable is probably collinear with something else, suggesting that you need to change the specification of your model.

Comment: Now it looks like `age` is collinear with `experience`. Thanks!